# Change the text color in webView

Tags: cocoa, webview, textcolor

Is there a way to change the text color for entire webView?
If it is could you provide me with some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easily doable from javascript

Answer (score 1):

A web view displays a web page, so do it the same way you would do it for any web page: define a CSS style (inline or in an external, referenced stylesheet):

```
* {
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

... then the page will be rendered with all text the designated color. This works because [the * selector applies to all elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204275/what-does-an-asterisk-do-in-css) and the [color property specifies the text color](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_text_color.asp).

Comment: Thanks, but by design I cannot put color in html, the color has to come from user preferences.

Comment: I *believe* you can forcibly include an external stylesheet with WebKit without referencing it from within the HTML.