# What is the meaning of * and * * in CSS selectors

Tags: css, selector

What is the meaning of `*`  and `* *` in the CSS-selectors below?

I have tried to collapse the definitions in one selector and that did not work well. If I comment the mainNav `* *` or collapse the `*` in the first selector, the layout is destroyed.

```
#mainNav { padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; }  
#mainNav * { padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; } 
#mainNav * * { padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0; }
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204275/what-does-an-asterisk-do-in-a-css-selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204275/what-does-an-asterisk-do-in-a-css-selector)

Comment: * is a universal selector

Comment: Maybe it can be to reset something like #mainNav h1 {padding-top: 16px} further up in your css, but not sure...

Comment: * is not actually universal selector? It selects everything for example `ul *` applies styling to all elements inside ul.

Answer (score 7):

`#mainNav` = any element with the ID "mainNav"

`#mainNav *` = styles any element that is a *child* of an element with the ID "mainNav" and all of its descendants

`#mainNav * *` = styles any element that is a grandchild of an element with the ID "mainNav" and all of its descendants

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/mRSWd/1/)

Comment: Shouldn't `*` be child and `* *` be grandchild?