# Is there anyway to not repeat ":hover"?

Tags: html, css

I have a lot of elements with the same rule when the mouse is hover.

```
h2:hover,h1:hover,p:hover,a:hover,h5:hover,h3:hover{...}
```

Is there anyway to not repeat the `:hover` part?

More specifically, is there any way I can add a psuedo-class (`:hover`) to multiple elements without repeating the psuedo-class?

Comment: Either use `class` as mentioned in the answers. Or you could think over using a css preprocessor like _less_ or _sass_ (the final result that is generated by them will however be a file that looks like you wrote it, but the preprocess would make your life easier, because you would not need to do this yourself).  But which approach you should choose depends on your use case.

Comment: There may be a means of tidying up your CSS by using the HTML structure of your page, but without your specific (relevant/[*SSCCE*](http://sscce.org/)) HTML it's very hard to say.

Comment: If you could give us the HTML structure they will be surely a way to do it without using an extra class for each element.

Comment: FYI: Compression will handle this kind of repetition quite well, meaning it shouldn't have as much effect on the amount of data transferred.

Answer (score 15):

Give them all the same class name and call the hover:event on the class name.

```
.supposed_to_hover:hover{

}
```

(You could also use jQuery to select all the elements and then call the `.hover()` on them!)

Comment: I think that gives more work because I want this code to all elements so I would have to write even more

Comment: @Diogo so consider using jQuery then. Personally, I would write them all out seprately.

Comment: Djogo, you supposed it to be a css optimization ?

Comment: @Diogo consider adding the class `supposed_to_hover` through jQuery to all elements, might be quicker!

Answer (score 6):

Could you not use a class?

```
.myHoverClass:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

And then have some HTML:

```
<h1 class="myHoverClass">Heading!</h1>
<a class="myHoverClass" href="http://www.google.com">Link!</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Referring to your comment above: **I want this code to all elements**

You can use the [asterisk selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204275/what-does-an-asterisk-do-in-a-css-selector) for hover as -

```
body *:hover{
    color: red; 
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pVbNx/)

Answer (score 1):

The CSS Selectors 4 draft [introduces](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#matches) the `:matches` pseudo class:

```
:matches(h1, h2, h3, h5, p, a):hover {...}
```

Currently there are experimental implementations of the old version of the draft, where it was called `any()`, in Gecko and Webkit:

```
:-webkit-any(h1, h2, h3, h5, p, a):hover {...}
:-moz-any(h1, h2, h3, h5, p, a):hover {...}
```

But the use cases for them are very limited (e.g. for development of an extension for a particular browser or iOS/FirefoxOS-specific mobile app) because it will require even more code duplication since you can't combine these selectors:

```
:-webkit-any(...), :-moz-any(...) { /* this won't work anywhere */ }
```