# CSS Selector: Star followed by class selector - necessary?

Tags: css, selector

I have seen the following css code:

```
*.myclass {
    /* some properties */
}
```

Or

```
div *.myclass {
    /* some properties */
}
```

are these any different from

```
.myclass {} div .myclass {}
```

?

Comment: I think it's not necessary, the specificity of `*` is zero so it has no use here. Normally the `*` is used alone such as `* {...}` or `div * {...}` ...

Comment: `div.myclass` is different to `div *.myclass` (note the space in between)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204275/what-does-an-asterisk-do-in-a-css-selector

Comment: @Pete Ah, sure, I meant to add the space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, the `*.myclass` selects any tag which has the class `myclass` so it is the same as using only `.myclass`.

In the second example `div *.myclass` means any tag with the class `.myclass` that is nested in a `div` which is different than `div.myclass` which means only `div` with the class `.myclass`.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/aCfB2/)**

The selector `div *.myclass` would select the same elements as `div .myclass` (note the space in between `div` and `.myclass`).

**To sum up :**

```
*.myclass = .myclass
```

and

```
div *.myclass = div .myclass
```

Comment: I was just typing "but is it not the same as using `div .myclass` " when you added your edit.  +1 for covering all the bases.

Comment: I missed the space on the `div .myclass`. So it's really better to leave out the `*` since it makes the code shorter.