# force div in full screen inside another div

Tags: html, css

The code below shows an image which is in image1 which seems it has a little border on its sides not going on the most left and top of the page. Can anyone help me out how? thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-image: url('images/main.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    border-style: none;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.image1 {
    background-image: url('images/freero1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="image1">

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried `*{margin:0;}`?

Comment: I'll post my comment as answer so you can select it as correct and others will find it more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this little CSS code, which will remove the default browser margin from all elements in the page (including the body):

```
*{
    margin:0;
}
```

You can learn more about the asterisk selector [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204275/what-does-an-asterisk-do-in-a-css-selector).