# CSS fill div with color completely

Tags: html, css

```
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
    <style>
        .top{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: blue;
            height: 15px;
            width: max-content;
        }
    </style>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div id="header" class="top"  >

    </div>

    <div id="content" class="middle">

    </div>
</h:body>
```

So,I'm trying to fill with color the whole div, but I always get a white border around it. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Are you reseting your CSS?  Is there a link you can post for us to see in detail?

Comment: expand on your description please. you want a blue background and white borders around the div ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should be added to your CSS file, browsers add a padding/margin to their view.

```
body,
html {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from what Lennart answered, you need to make sure there isn't other CSS causing this issue, take note of this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width

MDN notes that `max-content` is an experimental API that should not be used in production code.  Unless you are purposely using experimental API I would suggest you stick with percentage values, inherited values, or explicit values.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean that you want to remove margin around div use star *

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

but it is not clear if this is want you wanted.

Comment: It is worth adding that an *asterisk* (or 'star') is a "select all" css selector.  This topic covers it well:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1204290/4970964

Answer (score -1):

I'd also suggest that you make sure to follow HTML convention.

You currently have this:

```
<div id="header" class="top"  >

</div>
```

You should clean up the spacing so that it looks like this:

```
<div id="header" class="top"> <!--Notice that I cleaned up the spacing here --> 
</div>
```

Comment: That's not really a convention of HTML...  That's a spacing preference.

Comment: @Nol, I'd argue that all conventions are essentially just someone's preferences that have been made canonical. Just because someone doesn't follow convention does not mean their code won't work. I think you would be hard-pressed to find an HTML guide that suggests OP's spacing is the correct one. I'd also point out that this is merely a suggestion, that OP can either take or leave.