# Effect of an asterisk in a jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In the DevTools console of Chrome (version 63), I typed the following:

[image]

Notice the extra asterisk in the second query.

Both queries find the same element, but the second one is clearly getting a slightly different result. Also I wouldn't have expected the asterisk to be legal.

Can someone explain what effect the asterisk is having?

Note that this is not just asking about the use of an asterisk in a query, but about its effect when immediately next to an identifier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does an Asterisk (\*) do in a CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204275/what-does-an-asterisk-do-in-a-css-selector)

Comment: Basically it means, `any element with ID = 'right'`, which might not make much sense in itself. But consider `div#right`, which means, `any div with ID = 'right'`.

Comment: Okay, I've just realised what the second query really is: $('* #right'). Because of the missing space I thought *#right was some sort of wildcard. I'll delete this question in a few minutes.

Comment: You do know the difference between `* #right` and `*#right`, right? The first one searches among the descendants and the second one applies the `*` and `#right` to the same element.

Comment: Apparently I don't. Given that HTML ids are unique on a page, what would *#right do that #right doesn't?

Comment: Despite the confusion this is a valid question. It's precisely the fact that you would expect #right and *#right to match the same element, so what causes the prevObject to show up when an asterisk is present?

Comment: Also, the asterisk is legal in this context because it obeys the same grammatical rules as a type selector (such as div). It does not have to appear by itself in a compound selector.

Comment: What I can tell you off the top of my head is that jQuery passes lone ID selectors to document.getElementById(), while it treats anything else (that doesn't resemble HTML) as a selector. But I don't know enough about the prevObject property to provide a complete answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, thanks to the comments above, I understand what was happening.

`#right` means find the element with an id of 'right'. It will never return more than one element.

`*#right` means find any element with an id of 'right', in the same way as `div#right` means find any div with that id. It will return more than one element if there are more than one elements with that id. (There shouldn't be, but Chrome at least lets you do this.)

`* #right` means find the element with an id of 'right' that is also a descendant of another element. It will also return more than one element if there are more than one elements with that id.

Although the last case might seem redundant, it wouldn't match anything if the 'html' element was the only one that had an id of 'right'.

Comment: I would guess the asterisk versions are far less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk stands for **any** element.

`#right` and `*#right` should both return the same element, since an id is unique.

Comment: Yes, and the question states as much, but that's not what's being asked. Look closely at the results. Notice the presence of a prevObject property in the second result.

Comment: I didn't notice, but you are right. I will leave my answer though, so other won't make the same mistake as I did... :)