# How to avoid Background Image overlapping the Blocks

Tags: css, drupal-7

I have inserted an image in the background in my drupal 7 portal. And the css for it is ...

code :

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: 
   url
('https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/devuser/sites/all/BackgroundWallpapersforPortal/blue 
    image.jpg') !important;
 background-color:none;
 }
```

However, with this my image looks like this -

[image: image-overlap]

I don't want my background image to overlap the blocks. I have visited few websites, their background image doesn't overlap every new statement / every new entity. it stays embed to background. Please help.

**I want to Achieve this - where the blocks are also visible and there is a background image also.**

[image: image to achieve]

Comment: are you aware about the use of `*` ?

Comment: i tried with body{ ...//code} ..but it dooesn't work.

Comment: yes but are you aware about what does `*` mean? .. you don't want something that you explicitely did

Comment: ok...i got my mistake... but then...what is the solution ?

Comment: it depends on what you want .. your question is that you don't want the background on each element, so you need to not use that CSS. This is done, now explain what you want to achieve

Comment: can you provide a code snippet? or attach a screenshot of what you want to achieve

Comment: hey vira and temani, i attached a screenshot of what i want to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does an Asterisk (\*) do in a CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204275/what-does-an-asterisk-do-in-a-css-selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the background only to the specific elements you want it on, not everything. For example have a class for your menu items called "navigation" and set the CSS like this:

```
.navigation{
     background-image: url('https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/devuser/sites/all/BackgroundWallpapersforPortal/blue 
image.jpg') !important;
}
```