# CSS Attribute Selectors role*=user

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can anyone explain to me, please, what the following CSS selector will target?

```
[role*=user] > article a:not([href^=stage]) { 
    /* some rules here */ 
}
```

Comment: Also related but not a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204275/what-does-an-asterisk-do-in-a-css-selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector is targetting any anchor tag [`a`] which its `href` attribute doesn't start with `stage` [`:not([href^=stage])`]; that, is inside the an `article`, which is a direct child `>` of an element on which its `role` attribute contains `user`.

In the example bellow I styled the targets with a pinky color so that it can give an idea of what elements are selected by that:

```css
[role*=user] > article a:not([href^=stage]) { 
    color: fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<div role="user">
  <article>
    <a href="stage">loren</a> ipsum dolor <a href="not-stage">sit amet</a>
  </article>
</div>
```