# What does the unpaired single star sign mean after <style> in html?

Tags: html

I am taking HTML tutorial on W3School, and on [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_responsive_page), I don't understand the meaning of this single star sign. I am sure that it is not paired.

Below is the code:

```
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.../*HTML Classes*/
</style>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Trying to be helpful:
About box-sizing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing
About *box-sizing: https://html5please.com/#box-sizing
Wasn't sure about how to search for this before

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does an Asterisk (\*) do in a CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204275/what-does-an-asterisk-do-in-a-css-selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The * in css is called the Universal Selector. If you put a * in css, the styling is applied to everything. e.g. `<div>`

See [this link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/u/universal) for more details