# How can I find all elements in a webpage using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

This is a very straightforward question but surprisingly I cant find the answer on the internet. I am trying to find all elements presents in a webpage.  I know that in selenium to find elements you can say:

```
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name()
driver.find_elements_by_class_name()
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector()
driver.find_elements_by_name()
driver.find_elements_by_id()
```

and so on. But how can I find all the elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*But how can I find all the elements?*

CSS selector support `*` wildcard so you might ask for all elements using it

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("*")
```

See answers in [What does an asterisk (*) do in a CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204275/what-does-an-asterisk-do-in-a-css-selector) if you want to know more about `*` in CSS selector.

Answer (score 5):

Try xpath

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get('http://google.com')

ele = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id]')
for x in ele:
    print(x.tag_name, x.get_attribute('id'))
```

Gives

```
div gb
div gbwa
dialog spch-dlg
div spch
button spchx
div spchc
span spchl
span spchb
span spchi
span spchf
li ynRric
li YMXe
div duf3-46
a sbfblt
div tophf
div gws-output-pages-elements-homepage_additional_languages__als
div SIvCob
button Mses6b
ul dEjpnf
div YUIDDb
div lb
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically this xpath `//*` should represent all the nodes for a `static web site`.

Also, In typical Selenium, element has to be in view port then only Selenium can interact with it.

```
all_nodes = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*")
```

`all_nodes` is a list in Python, so you can do lot of stuff with list such as iteration or getting the size.

Note that, this should exclude the `iframe`, or `frame` or `frameset`.